# Is there a way to get the stored value of a truncated number in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with an ADO connection to an Excel workbook.

The data in the workbook, is entered from another system to around 28-30dp.  The data is taken to a Decimal field in Access which is (28,27) which is accepted as precision.

However when I transfer from

`Select * into` or a line by line `insert into` I only get the displayed truncated value through each way.

I have tried this also using a column in Excel, where the value = `=1/3` and I get the same result, like `0.3333333333333330000000000000`

Is there a way to get the stored value, not the truncated value.

Many thanks.

Comment: Excel workbooks only store data to 17 digits of precision, and only display 15 digits. The only way to read the additional 2 is to read the XML of the file (assuming an XML format workbook).

Comment: To put that in perspective, 15 digits is enough to express the distance from earth to the sun measured in the thickness of human hairs. 30 digits precision would allow you to measure the distance to Proxima Centauri in hydrogen atoms. You can't even express money with that kind of accuracy - during the few nanoseconds it takes to process such an amount, sufficient interest accumulates to change the result !

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the file in a different format?  For example:  If the data were saved in CSV format then there are data types which would allow for the precision that you need...